# Backbonejs simplest collection fetch

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I'm trying to download, parse and show a list, from the XML received from my server using Backbone.js. The code is like:

```
var Item = Backbone.collection.extend({
    url: "http://myurl.com/file.xml",
    parse: function() {
        console.log("parse");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("error");
    }
});

var View1=Backbone.view.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        var item = new Item();
        item.fetch();
    }
});
```

When I check it in the Chrome extension, the XML file is getting downloaded but the breakpoints placed in the `parse`, `success`, `error` directly lands to the `error`.

And it has 3 arguments, but I'm unable to extract any information from that.

Comment: I added a missing `"` after `.xml` when I was fixing your indentation.  I assumed that was just a typo in your example, does you real code have double quotes in all the right places?

Comment: @rock_win Does the breakpoint ever hit `log` inside parse method ? Did you try with other browsers ? Is the xml served with correct mime type?

Comment: no, it never comes inside the parse method, i tried adding the `Backbone.sync()` , it does comes there before landing to `error`, but its with the same arguments, i also tried debugging and going back to the source of Backbone, but its from some wrapper of Backbone, which tries to wrap already generated error ( not sure, where its getting generated)

Comment: I tried downloading the XML with normal $.ajax - and it came fine

Comment: can you post the error you get in the console? Looks like it might be cross domain access policy violation - is the XML on the same domain as the server from which you try to access it?

Comment: Does Backbone load xml files? I think you need to override the sync method to do the loading yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone does not support fetching XML, hence, you'll need to override the sync method to provide your own custom parsing functionality. If you don't want to have to mess with Backbone internals, try doing your $.ajax GET first, parse your response into a proper JSON Array and then use that array with a [Backbone#Collection-reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset).

[Backbone#Collection-fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)

> The server handler for fetch requests should return a JSON array of
>   models.

[Backbone#Sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

> With the default implementation, when Backbone.sync sends up a request
>   to save a model, its attributes will be passed, serialized as JSON,
>   and sent in the HTTP body with content-type application/json. When
>   returning a JSON response, send down the attributes of the model that
>   have been changed by the server, and need to be updated on the client.
>   When responding to a "read" request from a collection
>   (Collection#fetch), send down an array of model attribute objects.